After waking from sleep every command has input/output error and every app stops working
I put my laptop into sleep mode then when I wake it up most of my open apps when I try to click on them crash, others I can’t do anything with except force them to quit.
When I try to run any command in the terminal I get “input/output error” message and even plasmashell itself closes so I force a shutdown using the hardware power button.
I can consistently replicate this whenever I put my laptop into sleep mode. This is a Kubuntu 24.04 install from earlier this week.

It sounds a bit like / is in read only mode / the drive isn't accessible. As a test / workaround you could try and either disable or enable hibernation, depending on your current settings, and see if that changes anything.

Fiddling with power management-related options in the BIOS also could help in fixing this.

I don't see any related power management-related options in the BIOS I can change to fix this. Sleep was previously working on this same PC until I reinstalled the distro. Enabling hibernation hasn't helped.

Can you try and open a terminal, run lsblk and mount | grep sdXY, replacing sdXY with /'s partition, put the laptop to sleep leaving the terminal open, resume from sleep and run both commands again? Is the drive hosting the OS still listed? Is / still mounted rw?

If it's not clear from doing that what's the status of the drive after resuming from sleep, please post the output of sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdXY (do the same trick to run the command before putting the laptop to sleep so that hopefully it will be cached and accessible after resuming from sleep despite a possible inaccessible root partition)

Trying to do this after resuming causes both commands to give Input/output error.
Running mount | grep vgkubuntu-root prior to sleep:
/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root on /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell type ext4 (ro,noexec,noatime,errors=remount-ro)

Prior to sleep `sudo hdparm -I /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root` gives a blank output. I tried a variation without /dev or without /dev/mapper and neither worked.

Prior to sleep lsblk:
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1                259:0    0   3.6T  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1            259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2            259:2    0   1.7G  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3            259:3    0   3.6T  0 part
└─nvme0n1p3_crypt    252:0    0   3.6T  0 crypt
├─vgkubuntu-root   252:1    0   3.6T  0 lvm   /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
│                                             /
└─vgkubuntu-swap_1 252:2    0   1.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]

I can't seem to format these nicely in a comment so I'll repost to a pastebin here https://pastebin.com/ja14ULj7

You can edit your question to add details such as commands' output. Off the top of my head I can't think of other ways to check if the drive is still connected if those commands don't work after resuming. Try and post the last (say) 200 lines of /var/log/syslog (tail -n 200 /var/log/syslog) and journalctl --boot=-1 --no-pager, both after rebooting from the breakage, maybe something shows up there. Another thing I'd try to test the disk disconnected thing would be to boot from a live ISO and repeat the tests I suggested before
