I recently installed Kubuntu 24.04 on my laptop
Whenever I wake it up from sleep mode, most of my open applications crash upon clicking, while others become unresponsive, forcing me to quit them. Additionally, when I try to run any command in the terminal, I receive an "input/output error" message, and plasmashell itself closes, necessitating a hard shutdown via the power button.

Similar to https://askubuntu.com/q/1522270/243321 perhaps a trend is emerging.
